# RmDir - Path/File Access Error VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting to delete a folder using the RmDr function in VBA. On executing the snippet below, I get the following error:

> "Path/File Access Error".

```
    'Delete HTML Folder
    If (DirExists(fileDir)) Then
        Kill fileDir & Chr(92) & "*.*"
        RmDir fileDir
    End If
```

The documentation reads:

> Remarks An error occurs if you try to use RmDir on a directory or folder containing files. Use the Kill statement to delete all files before attempting to remove a directory or folder.- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rmdir-statement

My code already **deletes** all contents of the folder successfully, however I am still receiving this error.

Does any one have any experience with this error?

Comment: I don't think that this is a VBA problem. There are plenty of reasons why a folder (or a file) cannot be deleted - a process may have it locked, the user has no sufficient rights, the folder contains hidden files... . When this happens: Can you delete the folder manually?

Comment: I can delete the folder manually with no problem. The project is also located in an area, where Administrator rights are not required. Before the folder is deleted, I ensured that any of its contents were closed (checked in Task Manager).

Comment: Try using the FileSystemObject instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/filesystemobject-object

Comment: Does rmdir "foldername" delete the folder if you do it from the command line (making sure full folderpath given or you execute from the appropriate working directory) ?

Comment: Looks like it hasn't been mentioned, but when you delete a directory through code, if the folder is being accessed (open / viewed) by any user, it cannot complete properly, and will throw an error like the above.

Comment: HI, as you all said, it doesn't seem to an issue with the code. I looked into it a bit more and seemed to be an issue with my Macro settings of Office. In Access, I went to File >> Options >> Trust Center >> Trust Center Settings and set Macros to enabled. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As you all said, it doesn't seem to an issue with the code.
I looked into it a bit more and seemed to be an issue with my Macro settings in Office.

In Access, I went to **File >> Options >> Trust Center >> Trust Center Settings** and set Macros to enabled.

Now the target folder deletes successfully.

Thanks for the help.